# HTML: Checkbox - Unchecked value....Not working

Tags: java, html, bootstrap-4, thymeleaf

- I have an issue with Checked / UnChecked value setting of a checkbox.
- The issue is that if the checkbox is unchecked, then I do get a "" (empty string) returned ?.  - Any idea ?.
- This is what I have made so far.

  ```
  <h4 class="page-header" aria-atomic="true">Venue Category</h4>

  <input type="hidden" name="checkbox_1" value="0" th:field="${v.venueOptions}">
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_1" value="1" th:field="${v.venueOptions}"/>
  <label>Nightclub</label>
  ```

Any help is apriciated :)

Sincerely Liam.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a hidden input for the checkbox with a different ID:

```
<input id='testName' type='checkbox' value='Yes' name='testName'>
<input id='testNameHidden' type='hidden' value='No' name='testName'>
```

Before submitting the form, disable the hidden input based on the checked condition:

```
if(document.getElementById("testName").checked) {
 document.getElementById('testNameHidden').disabled = true;
}
```